Hitting api from swagger returns 500
I am using spring boot version 2.7.6 and for swagger using
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

Swagger config
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        HttpAuthenticationScheme authenticationScheme = HttpAuthenticationScheme
                .JWT_BEARER_BUILDER
                .name("JWT Token")
                .build();


        return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.demo.sv"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build().securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(authenticationScheme))
                .apiInfo(apiInfoMetaData());
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider webMvcRequestHandlerProvider(Optional<ServletContext> servletContext, HandlerMethodResolver methodResolver, List<RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping> handlerMappings) {
        handlerMappings = handlerMappings.stream().filter(rh -> rh.getClass().getName().contains("RequestMapping")).toList();
        return new WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider(servletContext, methodResolver, handlerMappings);
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfoMetaData() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("SOME SERVICE")
                .description("API Endpoint Decoration")
                .contact(new Contact("ME", "https://www.google.com/", "dev-team@gmail.com"))
                .license("Apache 2.0")
                .licenseUrl("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .build();
    }

    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("Bearer", "Authorization", "header");
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
        return Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference("Bearer", authorizationScopes));
    }
}

When i open swagger it works fine but when i hit any api, it returns an error
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        b {
            color: white;
            background-color: #525D76;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 22px;
        }
        h2 {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        h3 {
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        p {
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        a {
            color: black;
        }

        .line {
            height: 1px;
            background-color: #525D76;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1>
</body>
</html>

There is no error log on console, even when i debug api call. It reaches till return response statement on controller and on swagger has above response.
The api returns error even from curl and postman but if i remove swagger config and dependency it works fine
